# Website makes IE crash and requires restart (!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, crash

Website built on: Rails 3.0.3 & Heroku
Installed: Exception Notifier & New Relic

I am rewriting this question since my previous attempt was unclear and subjective, hope this works better.

I have a website where users can perform calculations. Once in a while I get reports from the users through my (one way) communication media that "the website crashes and tells me I need to restart IE, but it still doesn't work" which is pretty much as specific information I have been retrieving.

I get no timestamps so I can not look for it in the logs (Heroku only allows 2000 lines of error logs), I get no exception notifications and I cannot make the error appear myself so I would like your help with the following:

1. What would make a website crash in the way that it would tell the user to restart the browser? I have never even heard of that! What should I look for in the logs, if I can get timestamps for the errors?
2. Assuming it is a JavaScript-problem (which seems likely). How could I trouble shoot this issue? What tools can I use? Firebug does not give me any errors.
3. Assuming it is a IE version thing. How can I test the application in a systematic manner? (without installing/reinstalling different versions). Is there any applications that can test an application for different browsers?
4. It seems to work for most users/combinations. Do you have an older version of IE installed and can produce this error? Site: [www.countcalculate.com](http://www.countcalculate.com) (try any calculation).

Comment: Why don't you install IE and try it out for yourself? For all you know, someone was doing something else that crashed their computer at the same time they had your page open.

Comment: Oh, but I have. I can't reproduce the problem though. And it seems to work fine for most of the users as well, as far as I can understand. I think it is a matter of combined errors where IE seems to be a common denominator.

Comment: Possibly an addin they've got screwing things up. Get them to run IE in safe mode and try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have that type of communication with the users. There is only an anonymous "mail dropbox" where they can tell me about problems with the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (appearantly) limited to IE8 & XP-users. That combination conflicted with a bug in jQuery 1.6.2 according to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9981.

Downgrading to 1.6.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably related to a very intensive loop. For some reason IE thinks it's appropriate to block the UI thread while JavaScript is executing, so the whole thing will freeze up if your JavaScript breaks.

I can't reproduce the issue, so I'd suggest trying to get more detailed reports from your customers.

Comment: Could that loop also be in the Rails-code? Because I have very straight-forward javascript with no for/while or anything.